What Projection String could be used for creating something similar to the Chinese Vertical Map?
I recently saw this Vertical Map made by a Chinese Cartographer.

I want to create a similar map in QGIS, and for that, I need the CRS string or the Projection String.
The only detailed information I found is in this article, but it doesn't talk about the exact details of the Projection:
Looking at the world horizontally and vertically, what's the big difference? ——Interview with Hao Xiaoguang, the compiler of the vertical world map
What Projection string can I use in QGIS to make something like this?

It is called "Hao vertical projection" aka "Generalized Equip-Difference Parallel Polyconical  Projection".  Also related articles: https://www.flyingpenguin.com/?p=30490, https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/issues/1845. Maybe try writing to the inventor of the map projection? Here is his website (in Chinese): http://www.hxgmap.com/
